# Downloading a .ics file from a url without opening the browser?

Tags: calendar

Ok, this is a little complicated.

My uni allows my academic calendar to be downloaded as an ics file from a particular url that is specific to my calendar.

I have downloaded ICS Bot which transfers ics files into google calendar so I can view it on my HTC Sensation in a calendar.

If I download the .ics file and then the calendar's events change I will not have the up to date events. Therefore I need to regularly update the calendar myself by downloading the updated .ics file from the url.

I want an app/a single button that can download my .ics file without me having to open my browser, go to the page displaying my link and then clicking save as to get the new calendar.

Is there a way to do this???
Many many thanks.

**EDIT** I found some interesting discussions but I have no clue how to get a app from code:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

http://androidforums.com/developer-101/166103-downloading-file-url-caching-android.html

Comment: I'm guessing that [this other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/url-opens-rather-than-saves-file) is a generic version of this one. True? If so, I'd suggest deleting the other question. There's probably not enough information there to get good answers.

Comment: Could you not go to https://www.google.com/calendar/ and add the .ics as a calendar there?  Any calendar on the web app can be synced to your phone's Google Calendar

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.google.com/calendar (on a desktop computer) and login with the same gmail as your phone.

On the left hand side bar there is "Other Calendars".  Click the drop down to the right of that, then choose "Add by URL".

In the modal dialog, enter the URL of the .ics calendar file.  Then click Add Calendar.

Now open Google Calendar app on your phone. Hit the menu button --> More --> Calendars.  You should see the email you just added under your gmail account.  Enable syncing for it and then hit OK.  You should now have the most up to date copy of that calendar on your phone.

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your answer. I did do what you suggested but google calendar is very slow at syncing or doesn't sync at all as evidenced by this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=7c6b4213a42e6923&hl=en&start=80 Is there a way to sync with google calendar more often?

Comment: @helpplease I'm not sure, I haven't had syncing problems with the other calendars I have on my phone. From your launcher screen, hit  menu, go to settings, go to accounts & sync, and make sure background data and auto-sync are enable.  Then click on your gmail account and make sure "Sync Calendar" is enabled. That should be all that is required to auto-sync a calendar

Comment: @helpplease You can always force a sync by going to `Settings` -> `Accounts and sync` -> `Google account` -> `Sync now`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ICSSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nightlabs.android.icssync) would be a better option for you:

> ICSSync is an Android app for syncing calendars between an Android device and an ICS file (iCalendar) on a FTP/WebDAV server (plain WebDAV or SVN) or stored in a file (e.g. your Dropbox-folder).

So you can keep your calendar entries up-to-date automatically. Alternative candidates exist as well in the Playstore, e.g. [CalendarSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icalparse) (a bit expensive with ~ USD 10), or [CalDAV Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib) (~ USD 3).