# How can I save a file rather than open it?

Tags: browser, downloading

I want to change a URL somehow so that it prompts my HTC Sensation to save the file rather than open it.

Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: Also: if it is a download (and your device already downloaded it), it does save it to the /sdcard/download/ folder on your SD card

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you want to download some media (e.g. .mp3, .wav, .jpg) from a link, which for certain sites will try to open via browser.

Try long-pressing on the link for the menu, then select 'Save Link'. It will then save the content to `/sdcard/download` as  Bryan Denny♦ commented.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It needs to do both usually. Your [default] browser will download a file to the `/sdcard/download/` folder (as Brian Denny pointed out) and then open it from there. It can open it directly from the browser, but it will also be stored on your device.